# c# loop every minute - where to put the code?

Tags: c#

Currently I'm moving from java to c# and I'm full of crazy questions.
I'm trying new things on a windows form application and now,I would like to create a loop wich is executing a code every 1 minute,the problem is that I have no idea where to put this code.
For example,the form structure is like:

```
using System;

namespace Tray_Icon
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(5000);


        }

        private void notifyIcon1_BalloonTipClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Baloon clicked!";
        }

        private void notifyIcon1_BalloonTipClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "baloon closed!";
        }

        private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void option1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //some code here
        }

        private void option2ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //some code here
        }

        private void option3ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Option 3 clicked!";
        }

        private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            option1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(this, null);
        }

        private void closeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnWrite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//code here

        }
    }
}
```

Where should I put the loop code? :(

Thanks in advance for ANY replay!!!

Comment: Drop a timer control on your page, and explore its possibilities, especially the tick event.

Comment: Depending on when you want to run the code. Since the page is loaded? As soon as the page is built?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a Timer to your form:

[image]

set its `Interval` property to 60000 (one minute in milliseconds) and `Enabled` to `True`:

[image]

and attach an event handler to the `Timer.Tick` event, e.g. by double-clicking the timer in the Forms designer:

[image]

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do something here. It will be executed every 60 seconds
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to enable it! (Disabled by default)

Answer (score 7):

You would have to add a timer, and set the interval to 1000 miliseconds, and in the OnTick event you add the code with your loop

```
Timer tmr = null;
    private void StartTimer()
    {
       tmr = new Timer();
       tmr.Interval = 1000;
       tmr.Tick += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(tmr_Tick);
       tmr.Enabled = true;
    }

    void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code with your loop here
    }
```

Comment: Should I add the code somewhere inside of the form source code? How can I create OnTick event? Eh,sorry for asking so mutch. Its a desktop appliction

Comment: to create the event type in tmp.Tick then click + then click =  and then click tab button twice and VS will create the event for you

Comment: copy the code and add the StartTimer(); in some button event so you can test it, later you can place StartTimer(); in your form load or anywhere you want

Answer (score 0):

You can't put any loop code in here.

In your designer look for the `Timer` control. When you have that, configure it to run every minute and place your code in the `Timer_Tick` event.

Or create a timer manually in  code and respond to the event :) But for starters, doing it by the designer is easier!

Answer (score 0):

Drag a Timer component on the Form and doubleclick it. There you go with the code.

The Timer component runs in the main thread so you can modify UI components without worrying.

Alternatively You could create a System.Timers.Timer, which has it's own thread and has some advantages, but possible caveats when modifying UI components. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Background Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx?ppud=4) and put the code in the backgroundWorker.DoWork or use a Timer

Answer (score 0):

Use [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx):

```
System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

{
    aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    aTimer.Interval = 60000;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
}

private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime);
}
```

for using Timer see this tutorial: [C# Timer](http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer)

Answer (score 0):

How you do it in Java platform?

I think Java should be the same with .net. 
In fact, a form program is just normal program which contains a event dispatcher. The event dispatcher listen to the UI events and dispatch them to the event handlers. I think all the UI mode should like this, no matter Java or .net platform.

So generally speaking, you have 2 options:

1. Start the loop at beginning. In this case, you should insert your
   code in the constructor of the Form.
2. Start the loop when user
       click the button. In this case, you should insert your code in the
       event handler function.

Yes, as others mentioned, you should use the timer. But this should after you know where your code should locate. You also can use a endless loop with a sleep call. But timer is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Idea of timer is more better. But If you want to use threads. Then Follow this

1. Let me assume that You want to do it right from the start of program
2. You can write in body of function (event in fact) named Form1_Load as
3. Your actual code is just within while loop other code only to guide
4. I can guide if you don't know the use of threads in C#

---

```
bool button2Clicked = false;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    // A good Way to call Thread
    System.Threading.Thread t1 = new System.Threading.Thread(delegate()
    {
       while (!button2Clicked)
       {
          // Do Any Stuff;
          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000);  //60000 Millieconds=1M
       }
    });
    t1.IsBackground = true;  // With above statement Thread Will automatically
    // be Aborted on Application Exit
    t1.Start();
}
```